# Using Oracle, how to view non matching results?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two oracle tables with similar structures,
the main difference is that one is a subset of the other.
What I want to do is perform a join that will return all rows that are not in the subset table.

The issue is that the unique identifier is about 6-7 columns.
So I can not just do a `WHERE NOT IN` clause.
Does anyone know which type of join or how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your primary key is `(COL1,COL2,...)`:

The easy answer is to use the [`MINUS` set operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM T
MINUS SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM U;
```

If you feel the need, or have more complex logic, you might prefer using an [outer join](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm):

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 
FROM T LEFT JOIN U
USING(COL1,COL2)
WHERE U.ROWID IS NULL;
```

Please notice the `WHERE` clause that filters out the result set to only keep PK of rows *not* present in the `U` table.

In addition, all comparisons are only performed on the *primary key*, not checking the other columns. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e42f/13. According to execution plan, you will see that in my very simple example, the `OUTER JOIN` performs better.

---

That being said, the *subquery* syntax might perform even better, as the Oracle optimizer build *almost* the same execution plan than for the outer join. *But*, the key difference is the use of an *anti nested loop*, removing the need for the extra `NOT NULL` filter:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM T
WHERE (COL1,COL2) NOT IN (SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM U);
```

As far as I know, the `NOT IN` operator is the only way to perform the [anti join](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3181) you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `MINUS` query. Make sure you mention exact `column` names, i.e. exact number of columns with same `data type` in both SQLs in the MINUS query.

The result set thus returned is the difference in the rows between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

`where not in` is the answer.

the query will be something like this:

```
select blam, hoot, kapow
from schmarr
where blam not in
( select blam from smashy )
```

The column `blam` must have the following properties:

1. identifies a row in both the schmarr and the smashy tables.
2. is neither the naughty column 6 nor the naughty column 7 you mentioned.

the schmarr table is the superset table.  the smashy table is the subset table.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume Table-B is subset of Table-A.

```
    select * from Table-A left outer join Table-b on 
      Table-A.column1 = Table-b.column2 and 
      Table-A.column2 = Table-b.column2 and ....
```

where the columns1,column2,... are the unique identifiers